# Is this OK to remove censored observations from the survival analysis and model only those with events, if the number of events is small?

Tags: regression, modeling, survival, cox-model, censoring

As in the title. If we have a several hundreds of censored data and only a few dozens events, is this OK to remove the censored ones and use the Cox model on those with events only, ignoring the inferential part (when the power drops a lot)?

The purpose: will this approach better answer the question "how do the covariates affect the hazard?" if we leave only the "hazardous" observations - with the event of interest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You will end up with biased results, in general.

The Cox model gets its information from comparing the covariate for person who gets the event at a particular time with the covariates for people under follow-up who do not get the event at that time.

If you drop censored people, the comparison group is restricted to those who did not get the event at that time but will get an event while under follow-up, and that's a biased comparison.